# spiral 2d array starting from the bottom

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I want to create a spiral matrix consisted of numbers. Number 1 should be in the last row at the right side and other numbers should just follow the spiral path. The output of my code is different from the wanted result, and it also doesn't separate rows. I hope that you could help me solve these problems.

```
   \\ Expected result:        Output of my code: 1  2  3  4  5  10   15   20   25   24   23   22   21   
                                                16   11   6   7  8  9  14   19   18   17   12   13 
     9  10  11  12  13
     8  21  22  23  14
     7  20  25  24  15
     6  19  18  17  16
     5   4   3   2   1

    

#include <stdio.h>
 
void spiral(int n,int m,int arr[][m])
{
    int top = 0,            
        right = m - 1,      
        bottom = n - 1,     
        left = 0, 
        k;  
 
    while( top <= bottom  &&  left <= right )
    {
        //print top row
        for ( k = left; k <= right; k++ )
        {
            printf("%d  ",arr[top][k]);
        }
        ++top;
 
        //print right column
        for( k = top; k <= bottom; k++ )
        {
            printf("%d   ",arr[k][right]);
        }
        --right;
 
        //print bottom row
        for( k = right; k >= left; k-- )
        {
            printf("%d   ",arr[bottom][k]);
        }
        --bottom;
 
        //print left column
        for( k = bottom; k >= top; k-- )
        
        {
            printf("%d   ",arr[k][left]);
        }
        ++left;
    }
}
 
int main(void) {
    int rows = 5, cols = 5;
    int board[rows][cols];
 
    
    printf("\nSpiral printing:\n");
    spiral(rows,cols,board);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You sort of have the right idea. But, you need to separate *filling* the array from *printing* the array. The `spiral` function should just *fill* the array in this order:  bottom row, left column, top row, right column. And you need a separate function to print the array, which can be used to print the original array, and the spiral array.

Comment: Another tip is to use a variable to keep track of the next number that needs to be put into the array. For example, the declaration would be `int value = 1;` and in `main`, instead of writing `board[i][j] = 1 + i*cols + j;` you would write `board[i][j] = value++;` That doesn't make much difference for the original array, but it makes a world of difference when you are trying to create the spiral.